# How to legally add fake places on Google Map for Application Testing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have an application that detects nearby business of a particular genre. To test the app I want to add few fake business in the locality.

Does google provide any sandbox type of stuff for google maps?
 Can i add places via Javascript test my app and then remove them?

What should be the best way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you want to find business places with google maps javascript api without any databases in your backend script?
i think you must add places in your database and use it with google maps api to show/find places for your users.

Comment: In fact yeah you gave a nice idea. I can keep the business places latitude and longitude in my database and mark those points on map. Is that what you are saying ?

Comment: @Abhishek yes that's it, and if you use relational database like sql server, mysql or postgresql you can run a query that return nearest places for you.